# Custom post type query string

Tags: php, wordpress, query-string

I have followed the WordPress tutorial for this, but I can't get it to work.
http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule

What I have now:

> http://domain.com/timezone?country=netherlands&city=amsterdam

What I want to achieve

> http://domain.com/timezone/netherlands/amsterdam

When I go to that URL now I get redirected back to http://domain.com/timezone

I added this code to the functions.php

```
function custom_rewrite_tag() {
  add_rewrite_tag('%country%', '([^&]+)');
  add_rewrite_tag('%city%', '([^&]+)');
}
add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_tag', 10, 0);


function custom_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('timezone/([^/]*)/([^/]*)','index.php?page_id=4&country=$matches[1]&city=$matches[2]','top');
  }
  add_action('init', 'custom_rewrite_rule', 10, 0);
?>
```

and this code to my custom template

```
global $wp_query;
    echo 'country : ' . $wp_query->query_vars['country'];
    echo '<br />';
    echo 'city : ' . $wp_query->query_vars['city'];
    ?>
```

Am I missing something? 
Can someone please help?????

Comment: Did you flushed your rules? (by visiting the permalinks page in administration)

Comment: You should check on your htaccess and see how the rule is written by Wordpress. Maybe there is an other rule that take precedence of it, or the rule is invalid. It could help if you incorporate in your question the content of your htaccess file.